# Linear Algebra; expansion of brackets

Tags: linear-algebra

So, this is a really simple question , but if you have $A,B$ being $n\times n$ matrices how do you expand $\left(A-B \right)^{2}$?

The question is asking whether $\left(A-B \right)^{2}=A^{2}-2AB-B^{2}$

I tried this way: $\left(A-B \right)^{2} = \left(A-B \right)\left(A-B \right)$
=$A\left(A-B \right)-B\left(A-B \right)$
=$AA-AB-BA+BB$
=$A^{2}-AB-BA+B^{2}$

The question is can I group AB and BA? I don't think I can because I know that in general $AB\neq BA$

Essentially I'm just being hypercautious in case theres some strange way that it does equal $-2AB$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean 
to say  + $B^2$

and, right, don't assume the matrices commute!  :-)

(meaning that you can't do more, algebraically, with $-AB$ and $-BA$.)

Comment: thanks for pointing that out :) and cheers

Comment: you're very welcome, @Lincoln77! - cheers :-)

Answer (score 1):

You are correct.  $A^2 - AB - BA + B^2$ is as simple as it gets.

Answer (score 1):

$AB - BA = 2AB$ if and only if $A$ and $B$ [commutes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CommutingMatrices.html).

In general this doesn't hold, so $(A - B)^2 \neq A^2 - 2AB - B^2$ for most matrices.